# MATLAB: scatter plot from where each point has its own color

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Suppose I have a situation as follows:

```
clc; clear;
n = 1001;
m = 1000;
X      = linspace(0,1,n);
Y      = linspace(0,1,n);
randcolor = rand(m,3);
colorcode = randi(m,m,m);
```

For `i = 1, ..., n` and `j = 1, ...,n`, I would like to plot the points `(X(i),Y(j))`'s where the RBG color for `(X(i),Y(j))` is `randcolor(colorcode(i,j),:)`. I tried to do this the silly way: first declare

```
figure; hold on;
```

then do 2 nested loops, n steps each, and use `plot` to plot a single point n x n times:

```
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        plot(X(i),Y(j),'Marker','o',...
            'MarkerEdgeColor',randcolor(colorcode(i,j),:),...
            'MarkerFaceColor',randcolor(colorcode(i,j),:));
    end
end
```

This technically worked but it was slow and MATLAB ate up all of my memory when n was increased. What's a better way to do this please?

p.s. In my actual problem, `colorcode` isn't actually randomly assigned. Rather, it's assigned based on some divergence criterion for a filled Julia set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) instead of `plot` which allows you to specify the size and color of each point individually.

```
colors = rand(numel(X), 3);
S = scatter(X, Y, 100, colors);
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed to modify your answer a bit with meshgrid for my purpose but the suggestion of scatter is right on.